# Change a property on object declared with Object.create()

Tags: javascript

What is the problem?

```
var yie = Object.create({}, {

                'currentDoAction': {
                    value: null,
                    enumerable: true,
                    writeable: true
                },

                'success': {
                    value: function(result) {
                        this.currentDoAction = "should be changed";
                        console.log(this.currentDoAction); // prints out null ... why ?
                    },
                    enumerable: true,
                    writeable: true,
                }

});
```

see the comment in the `success` function where `this.currentDoAction` still appears to be `null` even though it should be changed in the line before.

Comment: Well, at first, you can write your question in better way. Finding what you are asking for isn't obvious (maybe you can describe it, in addition to code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've misspelled `writable` (nb: no "e"), so that property key is ignored and the default value of `writable: false` is used instead.

See http://jsfiddle.net/szLju/ for a working version.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can see is that you have a trailing comma and some browsers don't like this:

```
writeable: true,
               ^
```

Comment: in my experience only IE complains about extra trailing commas.

Comment: @Alnitak, still it's invalid javascript, no matter whether browsers accept it or not.

Comment: my (real) point was that if this mattered it would have caused a parse error, not code that doesn't work as expected.